# Is there a word that means "forced into somewhere despite not fitting"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Eg, what is a toddler doing when they force a square peg through a round role? More abstractly, what would you call it when you try to describe something via a model that doesn't really fit, and you make lots of stretches to try and get the situation to make sense with the model.

Eg: "I know we claimed this phenomenon could be described by theory X, but in retrospect we really just <BLANK>ed our observations into theory X's model".

**edit:** And just as I'm typing this I come up with "shoehorn". I'm pretty sure that's what I was trying to come up with. Still, I'd be interested in knowing if people think that actually does make  sense here.

Comment: I was going to suggest "shoehorned" before reading your last paragraph. :)

Comment: Shoehorned implies a tight fit, but a fit none the less. I'd suggest "I know we claimed this phenomenon could be described by theory X, but in retrospect we really just fed our observations into theory X's model *without prior validation*".  All models are wrong, some are useful - George Box.

Comment: jammed. you jammed it into x's model.

Comment: "Stuffed," "crammed," or, "though the model is not a good fit, it was the best of those tried" (echoes of @Phil Sweet's George Box quote).

Comment: May the *force* be with you! Anytime you force something into something else it means it didn't really fit there.

Answer (score 3):

You might make use of the following idiom:

***Procrustean bed*** - "a scheme or pattern into which someone or something is arbitrarily forced" (Merriam-Webster)

Procrustes was a figure from Greek legend who cut or stretched his guests to fit his bed.

If you need it as a verb, you might use the construction: ***__ was made to fit the Proceustean bed of __***.

Comment: You might, but you wouldn't ;)

Answer (score 1):

[ram](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ram) - to push or put (something) into a position or place by force. 
More importantly, it means to force passage or acceptance of.

Your example - I know we claimed this phenomenon could be described by theory X, but in retrospect we really just rammed our observations into theory X's model

[wedge](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wedge) - to force. (someone or something) into a very small or narrow place (literally or figuratively)

And there is always [drive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drive).

Answer (score 1):

> "I know we claimed this phenomenon could be described by theory X,
>   but in retrospect we really just **BLANK**ed our observations into
>   theory X's model".

**Retrofit**ted, (in which case change "in retrospect" to "in hindsight").

**Retcon**ned, (geeky, more suited to describing the ulterior politics of flexible official narratives and histories -- wouldn't be applicable to normal science, but might apply if a lab had become a real soap opera).

**Adapt**ed, (not slangy), **alter**ed, **modified**, **mutated**... choice depends on how one feels is about *theory X*.

**Force**d.

(**Shoehorn**ed is probably fine...)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, *force* is not a bad start. You could try "***force fit***," which is in abundant usage to mean something that is forced into a place or application where it just doesn't fit or belong.

Examples from [Wordnik.com](https://www.wordnik.com/words/force-fit):

> So rather than force-fit plans crafted for one part of the world onto another, Cisco created an entirely new geographic region devoted solely to emerging countries. [Inder Sidhu: Decisions without Tradeoffs](http://api.wordnik.com/v4/mid/76792f371b1b657fa32cc589922c2afa6e3613626188f298eb3f9045bed2b27de4cbcb18d611a91c81c52d679f0a00d2)

...

> What I ironically find more interesting is taking what few alternate “explanations” anti-evolution activists have offered - note how vague they are becoming in terms of “what happened when” - and trying to force-fit the evidence to see if any of those mutually contradictory alternate “explanations” has any merit. [Accretionary lapilli - The Panda's Thumb](http://api.wordnik.com/v4/mid/094be122638707bdcdc3c1a4506d505def90b843ecf375f976822508519a7506)

...

> McCain is too complex a character to force-fit into the caricatures that ideologues at both extremes are always peddling as the “truth.” [As Democrats Fight, McCain Seeks the Middle - The Caucus Blog - NYTimes.com](http://api.wordnik.com/v4/mid/07c10f6ff6ddd8e5e7e33d0aca4f59f00c1c5a294d8029097e35d3e27ccd033c)

...

Examples abound. In fact, one hears this usage all the time. I'd say it's the perfect for you.

Answer (score 0):

**contrived**

> *adjective*: obviously planned or forced; strained, artificial, or lacking in spontaneity; unnatural
>
> *verb*   (used with object), con·trived, con·triv·ing.   to plan with ingenuity; devise; invent. Ex. The author contrived a clever plot. to
>   bring about or effect by a plan, scheme, or the like; manage. Ex. He
>   contrived to gain their votes.   to plot (evil, treachery, etc.).
>
> (used without object), con·trived, con·triv·ing.   to form designs;
>   plan.   to plot.
>
> *verb*   (tr) to manage (something or to do something), esp by means of a trick; engineer. Ex. He contrived to make them meet.   (tr) to
>   think up or adapt ingeniously or elaborately. Ex. He contrived a new
>   mast for the boat.   to plot or scheme (treachery, evil, etc)
>
> Contrive - to make something happen, especially by using clever or
>   dishonest methods. Ex. We contrived to have an enjoyable holiday
>   inspite of the rain.

Maybe also, Engineered, Molded, Forged
Sources Google, dictionary.com, thesaurus.com