# What's a word that means to force something to fit?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a verb that means *the act of forcing a square peg into a round hole*, so to speak?  More specifically, in my case I'm facetiously suggesting that we take an absurd notion and try to fit the facts to the assertion.

> What's a teensy bit harder to ____ [about/to/for] this assertion is [contradictory evidence].

The best I've come up with are *reconcile* and *rectify*, but those have more to do with our response to these facts than the act of mashing them into a space in which they cannot fit in the first place.

*Explain away* works, but I'd rather have a single word, if possible.

*Conform* is probably the most exact word I've found for what I mean, but doesn't fit into my sentence structure, and it's not particularly playful.

If I cant find a single word, I'll probably just use...

> What's a teensy bit harder to square-peg into this round-hole assertion is [contradictory evidence].

...as it fits the playful, sarcastic tone, but again, I'd rather have a single word if possible.

Comment: Is it **folly**? That works with the last sentence, but your use case isn't consistent.

Comment: Folly isn't a verb though...

Comment: To [**contrive**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/contrive)?

Comment: That could work, though contriving is more about *fabricating* "facts" rather than fitting an inconvenient one into a system you like.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323855/is-there-a-word-that-means-forced-into-somewhere-despite-not-fitting?rq=1

Comment: We twist the facts, or we contort them, or we massage them. If that doesn't work, we torture them. [massage the facts](https://books.google.com/books?id=NnT44L7HZ8UC&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113&dq=%22massage+the+facts%22&source=bl&ots=yaDGnFTzk8&sig=ACfU3U3TYho6v3OoVnKmKf11LE4LVYc4gg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTrueMwvPoAhVHdt8KHTbtD4oQ6AEwDHoECBUQKQ#v=onepage&q=%22massage%20the%20facts%22&f=false)

Comment: What’s a little harder to ***rationalize*** about this assertion is ...

Comment: @KannE How many times have I told you not to force things? Just get a bigger hammer...

Answer (score 1):

You **jam** a square peg into a round hole.  [Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/jam):

> Push (something) roughly and forcibly into position or a space.

Comment: "What's a teensy bit harder to jam into this assertion is ..."?  I suppose that could work.

Answer (score 1):

How about **[square](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/square)** (M-W): to set right : bring into agreement

Your example sentence:

*What's a teensy bit harder to **square** with this assertion is [contradictory evidence].*

In addition to being a single word that captures the sense I believe you're seeking, **square** picks up the *square* in your analogy of the [contradictory evidence] to a *square peg*.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my word: **reckon**.

If someone has a better answer, though, I'm still interested.

Update:

A friend of mine suggested **shoehorn**.  That's a great word.

Comment: What's the complete sentence with "reckon" in it?

Comment: With regards to Steven Mnuchin's assertion that $1200 is enough to hold Americans over for 10 weeks... "What's a teensy bit harder to reckon into this ten-weeks assertion is that paper checks haven't begun to be sent out yet, and given the overhead involved, some people won't receive this ten weeks of life-sustaining relief for another five months."  Full post [here](https://www.facebook.com/dfoverdx/posts/10103675326747790).

Comment: You may be *force-fitting* **reckon** into this sentence. It seems to me to be a *square peg*.